# How to properly save the video from the camera on Android?

Tags: android, android-camera

I need to record and save video from camera to local storage (for example sd_card). So I try:

```
_mediarecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
_mediarecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
_mediarecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
_mediarecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/test5.mp4"); //test5.3gp тоже пробовал
```

also i try

```
_mediarecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(150000); // битрейт видео
_mediarecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(8000); // битрейт аудио
_mediarecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000); // частота дискретизации записи аудио
_mediarecorder.setAudioChannels(1); // количество каналов записи аудио
_mediarecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30); // фреймрейт записи видео
_mediarecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480); // размер картинки
_mediarecorder.setMaxDuration(0); // максимальная длительность записи
_mediarecorder.setMaxFileSize(0); // максимальный размер файла
```

But file which is created (test5.mp4) show distorted video with green lines.
Android 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Once check out whether the file test5.mp4 is created or not in the logcat.

Comment: File is created '/sdcard/test5.mp4'